# Unity ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range. Parameter name: i

Tags: c#, regex

I get this error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: i
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection.get_Item (Int32 i)
   ServerTime.SplitString (UnityEngine.WWW www) (at Assets/Script/Common/ServerTime.cs:48)
   ServerTime+<GetTime>c__IteratorB.MoveNext () (at Assets/Script/Common/ServerTime.cs:31)
```

Error link:

```
time = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2} {3}:{4}:{5}"
```

My code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class ServerTime : MonoBehaviour{

private string url = "http://www.beijing-time.org/time.asp";
private string time = string.Empty;

public delegate void GetTimeBackCall(string time);
private static GetTimeBackCall call;

public void GetServerTime(GetTimeBackCall backCall) 
{
    call = backCall;
    StartCoroutine("GetTime");

}

public IEnumerator GetTime()
{
    //Debug.Log("Start Requesting server time");

    while (true) 
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(url);
        yield return www;                   //Blocked here, waiting for a response after the return
        if (www.isDone && string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error) && www.text.Length >= 10)
        {
            SplitString(www);
            break;
        }
        //Debug.Log("Re-request the server time");
    }

    yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
}

private void SplitString(WWW www)
{
    //Use regular matching expression
    string patten = @"[0-9]{1,};";
    Regex regex = new Regex(patten);
    MatchCollection result = regex.Matches(www.text);

    //Time Organizational
    time = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2} {3}:{4}:{5}"
                         , result[0].Value.TrimEnd(';')
                         , result[1].Value.TrimEnd(';')
                         , result[2].Value.TrimEnd(';')
                         , result[3].Value.TrimEnd(';')
                         , result[4].Value.TrimEnd(';')
                         , result[5].Value.TrimEnd(';')
                         );


    if(time.Length >= 10)
    {
        call(time);
    }

    //Debug.Log("EU:" + time);
}
}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint on your "time = string.Format(..." line and see what the size of the result collection is. From the error, I suspect it is less than 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the `SplitString()` method. That method has all sorts of potential issues including a null reference issue so cleaning up this method would be helpful long-term.

Here's an example how to solve your particular problem. As you do not know into how many elements your regular expression is slitting the passed in value you better loop through them instead of assuming you have six of them. This should work in principle; I typed this without testing it:

```
private void SplitString(WWW www)
{
    // Use regular matching expression.
    MatchCollection result = new Regex(@"[0-9]{1,};").Matches(www?.text ?? string.Empty);

    // Time Organizational. (if you used a StringBuilder it could be a touch faster)
    string time = string.Empty;
    foreach (var item in result) // Loop through all results no matter how many.
        time += time + item.Value.TrimEnd(';') + ":";
    time = time.TrimEnd(':'); // Get rid of the last unnecessary colon.

    // Unsure what this does, but your original code contained it.
    if(time.Length >= 10)
        call(time);
}
```

P. S. If you wrote unit tests you would have found the problem yourself ;-)

Comment: i get error in this line : time += time + item.Value.TrimEnd(';') + (":");             System.Object does not contain any definition for 'Value'